# problem with linear regression

Tags: r, regression, time-series, multivariate-regression

I made a linear regression multiple model, I've got all the parameters insignificant with high p value, I get this result:

[image]

The variables are time series. Rates except Polity which is natural number from (-10 to 2)
I tried also a simple regression with each explicative variable, it's also not significant 
What could be the cause of such a result ?
How to fix that ?

Comment: What was your rationale for removing the intercept? If you are analyzing time data, why are you choosing a linear regression instead of a multilevel model or some other method that considers the non-independence of measurements at different time points? Also, non-significance doesn't mean something is wrong. Predictors may be non-significant because the predictors are not related to the outcome. Statistical significance is not the goal; arriving at an accurate result is the goal.

Comment: I removed the intercept cause the mean of dependant variable is approximate to zero. So you think that multiple regression is not the appropriate model ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to assume that you've done something wrong that needs to be fixed. Rather, perhaps you're wrong in your prior belief about the population: that the independent variables you've selected have a large relationship with the dependent variable. If so, small coefficients and large $p$-values are to be expected.